# trying to concat two sections in one query

Tags: mysql, concatenation

My query is:

```
SELECT concat(fname,lname) as Fullname FROM users
```

The output it first name and last name come under the column Fullname.

My question is. I also want to include concat(dob,phone) as ExtraInfo .. in the same query though don't know how to do both in one?

Comment: SELECT concat(fname,lname) as Fullname, concat(dob,phone) as ExtraInfo FROM users

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan how stupid of me.. thank you